# Rails 4 validates if num1 > num2 > num3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, numbers

I'm currently facing 2 problems using custom validation on Rails 4. First problem, how can I make the following code more generic and efficient (if it's possible) ?

```
validates :p1, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: false }
validate :p1_is_greater_than_p2_and_p3
validate :p2_between_p1_and_p3
validate :p3_is_less_than_p2_and_p1

def p1_is_greater_than_p2_and_p3
  if self.p1.present?
    errors.add(:p1, 'p1 must be greater than everything') unless 
      (self.p1 > self.p2) && (self.p1 > self.p3)
  end
  true
end

def p2_between_p1_and_p3
  if self.p3.present?
    errors.add(:p2, 'p2 bewteen p1 and p3') unless 
      self.p2.between?(self.p1, self.p3)
  end
  true
end

def p3_is_less_than_p2_and_p1
  if self.p2.present? and self.p3.present?
    errors.add(:p3, 'p3 must be inferior to eveything') unless 
      (self.p2 > self.p3) && (self.p1 > self.p3)
  end
  true
end
```

It's really bloated and dirty, isn't it?

Second issue, on `errors.add`, I can pass a symbol and an error message. However, if I don't pass any message, how can I define a custom yml key for my locales ? such as :

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        prices:
          attributes:
            custom_key_message_here: 'p1 must be greater than everything'
```

I want to keep this seperation of concern between locales and model. However, if I don't pass any message, it's show me `is invalid`. I would like something more explixit.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick look at the [`numericality` validator](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality), could you not just use:

```
validates :p1, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than: :p2 }
validates :p2, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than: :p3 }
validates :p3, presence: true
```

As long as `p1 > p2` and `p2 > p3`, you shouldn't need to compare `p1` and `p3` directly. This is assuming all three values must be present, but you could probably adjust things to work if they're optional.

Comment: Perfect. On forums I saw that was not possible since `greater_than` only accept integer so I didn't even try it myself using attributes. Works like a charm. Thanks